# How to call RESTful web service remotely

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have been reading tutorials on how to build REST web services using Jersey and Tomcat. I have made a small test web service in Eclipse, deployed it on a Tomcat server and when I call the URI http://localhost:8080/TestService/rest/HelloWorld/ from browser it works fine.

My question is how do I make a call to this web service from another PC. I tried replacing 'localhost' with the public IP (168.58.x.x) and call it via browser of another PC, I am not getting a response. I am not sure if I am missing to do something here or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect the correct port on your router, too.

1. Log in to your router
2. Find Network > NAT > Port Forwarding
3. Add a rule for your web Service that redirect the port 8080 to your local (LAN) ip

Comment: So the server.xml in apache conf foler says port=8080 and redirectPort=8443. So I need to port forward 8080 port to 8443 for the machine where I deployed the web service right?

Comment: I meant the web service port. You need the redirect the web service port to your machine's local ip on your router. If you Web Service use port, let say, 5990 then you create a redirect rule on your router that redirect the traffic sent to this port. Then you enter the url [your.public.ip]:5990 in your browser

Comment: Can you tell me steps to do this? I have never done this before. By default Tomcat uses port 8080 for web service calls